# Where is my Amped Up Hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

From [winterbash2016.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/amped-up)

> **Amped Up**
>
> share a link to a question on social media that gets 5 clicks

I share [one of my Movies & TV question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65221/which-of-the-previous-star-wars-films-does-one-need-to-watch-before-rogue-one) on [twitter](https://twitter.com/Ankit_Om_Sharma/status/810757437217275904)
 with the share link under the question. Below is the twitter stats:

[image]

More then 12 hours has been passed since I crossed 5 link clicks, but still I did not get the hat.

So why I didn't got the hat yet?

Comment: Now 10 clicks and still no hat

Comment: I'm reopening this because we've found a bug and for some reason we're not getting all the clicks from the share.  The devs are looking into it, but it's a deep, dark rabbit hole they are diving into.

Comment: @bluefeet So I should wait for my hat or try again ?

Comment: You can keep trying, or just wait till they get it resolved.  It's definitely working for some people because the hat has been awarded.

Comment: @bluefeet is this affecting the relevant badges as well?

Comment: Not sure @ShadowWizard

Comment: Did tried again https://twitter.com/Ankit_Om_Sharma/status/811278061111013376

Comment: Still didn't got it :/

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it is obsolete and attracting spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There definitely was a bug here.  It was very obscure and it took the developers several days to figure out why you were not getting accurate counts from sharing your link via Twitter.

The basic gist of the fix from [Marc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) is:

> As reported, t.co shortened links were not being recorded correctly due to a bug in our code. Most other url shorteners should be fine, and direct links (without shorteners) will have been fine. We have fixed the bug and future clicks should be recorded correctly. Additionally, there were some other subtle problems with timing and browser cache/prefetch, which have also been fixed.

The fix has been deployed and should work going forward for users sharing links.

Comment: I did got the hat in third attempt. Thanks for the help